# Can't save json data to variable (or cache) with angularjs $http.get

Tags: json, angularjs, web-services, rest

I have weird angularjs problem. I'm trying to fetch data from Rest Webservice. It works fine, but I can't save json data to object. My code looks like:

```
services.service('customerService', [ '$http',  '$cacheFactory', function($http, $cacheFactory) {
var cache = $cacheFactory('dataCache');
var result = cache.get('user');
this.getById = function(id){
    $http.get(urlList.getCustomer + id).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        result = data;
        cache.put('user', result);
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //
    });
    return cache.get('user');
};
}]);


services.service('customerService', [ '$http', function($http) {
var result;
this.getById = function(id){
    $http.get(urlList.getCustomer + id).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        result = data;
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //
    });
    return result;
};
}]);
```

Both methods not working. Am I missing something?

PS: "console.log" method succesfully printing json data.

Edit:

After some editing I came out with something like this:

```
services.service('customerService', [ '$http', function($http) {
var result;
this.getById = function(scope, id){
    $http.get(urlList.getCustomer + id).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        result = data;
        console.log(data);
        scope.userData = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //
    });
    return result;
};
}]);
```

in controller:

```
customerService.getById($scope, id);
```

Anybody knows any better way to save data in variable (to cash it for other controllers) and display data on screen? I want  to skip as much boilerplate code as I can :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$http.get` is asynchronous. When `cache.get` or `return result` are executed, HTTP request has not completed yet. How are you going to use that data? Display in UI? E.g. try the following:

```
// Some View
<div>{{myData}}</div>

// Controller
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('yoururl').success(function (data) {
    $scope.myData = data;
  });
});
```

You get the idea?

Check out how promises are used. From your service function, you can return the promise that $http.get returns, and you can use it in controllers/directives as follows:

```
// in your service
this.getById = function(id){
  return $http.get(urlList.getCustomer + id).success(function (data) {
    return data;
  });
}

// in directive/controller
customerService.getById(someId).then(function (customer) {
  $scope.customerId = customer.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your method should look like, `success` is a promise which is asynchronous, which means your `return result;` was invoked before the `success` was triggered

```
return {      
        getById : function(id){
            return $http.get(urlList.getCustomer + id).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                return data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //
            });
        };
}
```